# Perfect way to ask about existence of a product in the shop

Tags: usage

In my native language, it’s very popular to ask for availability of the clothes in the store, like:

- “Do you have this item of ... size?”.

Machine translation would propose

- “Haben Sie ... Größe?”

However I have been argued that it’s not cool to use such sentence translated one into one to German and that it spots my tourist’s nature.

*In English* it would mean that I ask the salesman whether he owns such an item by himself (for personal use). It would be more appropriate to ask `„Is there ...?“`.

*In German* that should sound like `„Gibt es ...?“`.

Is that the same for a shopping situation? What is the perfect way to ask questions about item's availability?

Comment: What would be your one into one translation into German? Don't you know any German? Did you try DeepL translation service? We aren't out here for individual translation service. Please take the tour, to inform about our policy.

Comment: My variant is “Haben Sie ...?“ However it doesn‘t sound right in the shopping context with a native speaker. They say that I ask whether they own it or not. That’s simple and strange.

Comment: @Tourist101 I can't see what's wrong with _Haben Sie..._ And regarding the argument that you ask whether they own it or not - well, as long as you don't buy it the shop _does_ own an item. :)

Comment: "Haben Sie ...?" Oder "Haben Sie ... zu verkaufen?" Probably it is not the best, but all the shoppers understand it very well. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Good to hear that it sounds ok. The main doubt was that in English saying „do you have shoes of another size“ to the salesman is not really appropriate. It should be „are there shoes of another size“? The first question is naturally asks whether salesman itself (not the shop) owns the shoes for his personal use :) Therefore I was adviced to use „Gibt es ..“. Is it the same in German?

Comment: @userunknown Very warm welcome to a new member of the platform! The question already states that it is about style and situation appropriateness, so referring to a machine translation is not a good advice and it is rather obviously so. I think we could become better at helping people, trying to find their real need, even if the question might not be put in the best way. And this question is pretty clear in what the need is.

Comment: I don't see how this question would be off-topic. How to ask for items in a shop is not one of *specific questions of general interest and to help you learn and understand*?

Comment: Asking "gibt es Kleider in Größe x" is not so direct towards your intention to buy them in this store. It could be answered like "ja solche Kleider gibt es - aber nicht hier" :-) The question "Haben Sie..." is fine, I never experienced a store employee to relate it to personal belongings.

Answer (score 8):

It's perfectly fine to ask

> Haben Sie grüne Pudelmützen?

or

> Haben Sie diese Schuhe auch in Größe 46?

You could also just state

> Ich hätte gern ein Paar rote Gummistiefel.

Comment: Another possibility, but rather seldom and maybe a bit old-fashioned: "Führen Sie auch rote Gummistiefel?"

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: „Ja, aber wir haben keine vorrätig.“

Comment: @CarstenS Ah ja, Feinheit!

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach  "Führen Sie auch [whatever]" is a sentence that could be found in a language guide of the 1950s, but nobody, really nobody, even not the most over-bourgeoise lady in a mink fur coat would today use that phrase in real life. You wouldn't even use it in a formal business letter. The only person I can imagine saying this is someone who had the bad luck of having one of these old language guides.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I do use it in normal life. I am not an over-bourgeoise lady in a mink fur coat though. So you are right.

Comment: Does omission of a note about "gibt es [hier] ..." mean that you deem it wrong? I don't think it is.A matter of colloquial register, sure.

Comment: @vectory "Gibt es rote Gummistiefel?" "Ja, aber nicht hier." ;) I wouldn't say "gibt es [hier] ..." is wrong. But it sounds clumsy to my ears. I think it would be exactly, what OP was trying to avoid.

Comment: "Gibt es das auch in XXL" would be perfectly colloquial. What's clumsy about it? *Es gibt nichts dagegen einzuwenden.*